# Python matplotlib not importing due to failure to import unichr

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 with Python 2.7.5+, and whenever I try to import the `matplotlib` package, I get an error.  Specifically, my test script has only the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

When I run the test script, here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 34, in <module>
    import matplotlib.collections as collections
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 56, in <module>
    import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 22, in <module>
    from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 26, in <module>
    from six import unichr
ImportError: cannot import name unichr
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What version of `six` did you install, and how did you install it?

Comment: Also, is there any chance you accidentally created a file named `six.py` that's hiding the installed module that `matplotlib` is depending on? (Even if you later deleted it, there could still be a `six.pyc` around getting in the way.) If you're not sure, try `import sys; print(six.__file__)` and see what you get.

Comment: @abarnert I don't remember installing `six`.  When I run `import six; print(six.__file__)`, I get: `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.pyc`.

Comment: @abarnert: I think you mean `import six`.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Thanks. Fortunately, the asker figured out what I meant even if my fingers couldn't. :)

Comment: @synaptik: OK, most likely you got `six` by doing `pip install somethingelse` or `apt-get install somethingelse` which depended on `six`. At any rate, it looks like it's installed correctly, and not hidden by anything else. (You did run that `import… print` test in the same directory you're running your failing program from, right?) So the next step is `import six; print(six.unichr)`.

Comment: If this shows something like `<built-in function unichr>`, then there's something weird about the `sys.path` when you're running your program, so that's what has to be debugged and fixed. If it instead gives you a `NameError` or similar exception, then your `six` is somehow broken or very out of date, so that's what needs to be fixed. (If it does something else… then I have no idea, but we can start with sacrificing a chicken and see where that goes.)

Comment: @abarnert when I try to `print(six.unichr)`, it gives me: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'unichr'`

Comment: OK, one last thing (but I think I know the answer now, so I'll write it up and then delete it if I was wrong): `print(six.__version__)`. If it's less than '1.4.0', that's your problem.

Comment: @abarnert Yep!  It's `1.3.0`

Comment: Can you report this as a bug on github? 1.3 is what we list as the minimum version, which is apparently wrong.

Comment: Thanks.  This will be fixed for 1.4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You apparently have an outdated version of `six`.

The `unichr` wrapper was added in version 1.4.0, as seen in [`CHANGES`](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/src/default/CHANGES?at=default#cl-135). I'm not sure exactly when 1.4.0 was released, but the fix for [issue #25](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/issue/25/add-unichr) was committed on 2013-05-18, so… some time after that.

So, if you `print(six.__version__)`, and it's anything less than '1.4.0', that's your problem.

Depending on whether you're installing packages with `pip` or with your system's package manager, the solution is going to be something like one of these:

```
$ pip install --upgrade six
$ apt-get install six
$ brew install --upgrade six
```

… etc.

---

But meanwhile, `matplotlib` shouldn't be requiring 1.3 but using features only available in 1.4. Your GitHub issue [matplotlib#3538](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3538) should get this fixed.

Comment: Added issue on github.

Comment: @synaptik can you provide a link to the issue you submitted? thanks.

Comment: @jcragun [matplotlib/matplotlib#3538](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3538)